# win32api.GetCursorPos() questions

Tags: python, winapi

So I've been messing around with having my mouse seize all over the screen, and that is easily done when I make the def, and tell its cords things like (32, 21) - but, whenever I use a variable to substitute it, it throws an error saying "SetCursorPos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

What should I do?

```
def mPos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))

#A bit of code later

def start():
    global h_x
    global h_y #My reasoning for using globals is for the incoming for loop - I don't
    #know how to stop it from creating new "h_x"'s and ignoring ones I already set.

    h_x, h_y = win32api.GetCursorPos() #This works fine.

    print "Mouse was at " + str(h_x) + ", " + str(h_y) #This also displays normally.

    for i in range(countdown): #Consider countdown to be something like "5".
        mPos(h_x,h_y)
```

`mPos(h_x,h_y)` is the source of my current problems. I want it to take numbers that those two already got from `GetCursorPos()` to be re-used for `SetCursorPos()`, but I don't quite understand how I'd do that, or what the error even means.

I even had it to were it was:

```
 mPos((h_x,h_y))
```

And python threw a report that it couldn't even tell what kind of error that was...

Comment: Indent your code correctly.

Comment: That's weird, I did when typing it out. Countdown is a value changed into an Int by an input from the person - basically it tells the loop how many times to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear. You should pass **a sequence** that represent coordinate.

```
import time

import win32api

def mPos(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))

# OR
#
#def mPos(coord):
#    win32api.SetCursorPos(coord)

def start():
    h_x, h_y = win32api.GetCursorPos() #This works fine.
    print "Mouse was at " + str(h_x) + ", " + str(h_y) #This also displays normally.
    return h_x, h_y

h_x, h_y = start()
for i in range(5):
    mPos(h_x + i * 10, h_y + i * 10)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I never really worked with Python before, so a lot of it's messages are a bit strange to me. If you don't mind, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: @user2998677, Replace `win32api.SetCursorPos(x,y)` with `win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))`. The first one call `SetCursorPos` with two arguments. The second one call `SetCursorPos` with a tuple with two items.

Comment: The same error still rears it's head - though at least its somewhat fixed

Comment: @user2998677, I don't understand what you mean: `The same error still rears it's head`.

Comment: I added your edit, but it still says that it's getting two arguments. I think I messed with something on my end

Comment: @falsetru You sure? http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetCursorPos_meth.html

Comment: Wait, i think you're probably right about that

Comment: @aIKid, That does not match the actual signature.

Comment: Yep, in other threads it's `setCursorPos((x,y))`.

Comment: @user2998677 what is the python version you're using?

Comment: @aIKid, It does not relevant to Python version, but pywin32 version.

Comment: @falsetru Probably.. you seem to know more about this, so i'll just handle it to you.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.6Py with pywin32 VR218 for Python2.7

Comment: 2.7.6? The version released 6 days ago?

Comment: @user2998677, I added a complete code. (edited `start` to return the coordinate instead of using global variables). Try it.

Comment: @falsetru dah, we both missed that silly mistake, and David answered it..

Comment: @aIKid, Yeah, I only tested `win32api.SetCursorPos` in the interactive mode at first ;)

Comment: @user I hope you did not feel obliged to accept this answer. falsetru hectored you to accept even though his advice was wrong from the start. He then edited the answer correcting his mistakes, after reading the other answer. I am not impressed by his conduct in this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I changed the code after running the entire code myself, not after reading your answer.

Comment: @user2998677, It's okay to unaccept the answer to accept David Heffernan's one.

Comment: @falsetru It's fine for your answer to be accepted. It is now accurate. It doesn't matter how you came to that knowledge. I note that my answer had a downvote reversed. The point is that you should not have psuhed for an accept so strongly. I think in the future I'd like to see you be a bit less pushy. The user will accept when they are ready.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined like so:

```
def mPos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos(x,y)
```

It receives a single argument. But you call it passing two arguments. Which leads to the error that you report.

Beyond that the function itself is broken, as well as your calls to it, because x and y are not defined anywhere in the function. Change the function like this:

```
def mPos(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos(x,y)
```

Now you can pass the function the two arguments. Like this:

```
mPos(x, y)
```

Finally I would advise a better name than mPos which is rather passive. Make the function be an imperitive instruction. I'd call it SetMousePos or similar.